# How to avoid NaN in a weighted average?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, numpy

Here is my data frame df:

```
       str1    str2     str3     str4    
key1     3       4       2        5
key2    NaN      3       4        4
key3    NaN     NaN     NaN       2
```

and a vector w:

```
 [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
```

I usually use  `df.T.dot(w)` to compute the product between a dataframe with a vector. But I would like to know how can I avoid NaN value by re-weighting the vector and computing as long there is not a full column of NaN.

Example for my case:

For the first column I would like the vector to be equal to `v = [0.2+0.3+0.5, 0, 0]` and compute `[3, NaN, NaN]` times `[1, 0, 0]`.

For the 2nd column, I would like `v = [0.2+0.25, 0.3+0.25, 0]`.

For the 3rd column, I would like `v = [0.2+0.25, 0.3+0.25, 0]`.

For the 4th column, I would like `v` unchanged because no NaN.

Expected output:

```
          str1   str2  str3    str4
    0      3     3.45   3.1     4.7
```

Comment: `df.fillna(0).T.dot(w)` ? What would be the expected output?

Comment: Where does the `[0.2+0.25, 0.3+0.25, 0]` comes from?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I don't know why I didn't think of replacing `nan`... That is actually the better solution.

Comment: It comes from the fact that `[str2,key2] = NaN` so the corresponded value from the vector (0.5) is split to the others values of the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a NaN-value should mean "weight = 0" in the inner product, then modify your dataframe like this before doing the computation:

```
df_without_nans = df.fillna(value=0.0)  # 'value' can be dropped
dot_product = df_without_nans.T.dot(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an easy way to take care of `nan` values. You might have to create your own dot product function to handle those values. Something like this might work:

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x * [1, 0, 0]).sum())
```

The pandas `sum` method automatically ignores `nan` values, so you don't have to explicitly find the values yourself. You'll likely replace `[1, 0, 0]` with reference to some other array of your weights. I'm not sure how you have it arranged now to integrate it into the above suggestion.